# I want to read a file that is saved in hard drive to read through assembly language

Tags: assembly

The codes shown below is my structure to read the file that has been saved in my computer. How can i make my program to read it from the hard drive? The codes shown below is a sample of codes that i will be using in my program

```
code segment

main proc far

;Housekeeping section

assume cs:code,ds:data,ss:stacks

mov ax,data ;establish addressability

mov ds,ax   ;to data segment

;Main Process Section

xor ax,ax

xor bx,bx

xor cx,cx

xor dx,dx

;open file

mov ah,3Dh

mov al,0

mov dx,offset file

int 21h

;read file

mov bx,ax

mov ah,3Fh

mov cx,40

mov dx,offset buffer

int 21h

jc error

;closing file

mov ah, 3Eh

int 21h

error:

mov ax, 4c00h

int 21h

main endp

code ends

data segment

file    db "file.txt",0  <----------- what should i put here to make my   codes read file from hard drive

buffer  db 42 dup(?)    ;data buffer    

data ends

stacks segment para stack 'stack'

dw  32 dup(?)

stacks ends

end
```

Comment: Your file name is "???.txt". "?" is illegal character for file names (use a normal name, like "hn.txt"). The rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: I left this intentionally because I don't if I have to write any path to read outside file

Comment: Another problem: after opening the file, save AX into a DW variable because it's the file handler, you will need it for further operations (like reading and closing). Finally, to check if data was read try to display it.

Comment: It's ok if you want to add a path for your file. Warning : if you are using EMU8086 your file doesn't need a path, but store it in c:\emu8086\MyBuild (or wherever you installed it).

Comment: Eww.  File I/O is not what assembly language is supposed to be used for (anymore.)  Ah well, learning int 21h stuff might still have a use I guess.

Comment: i have to use it from my huffman compression and decompression project

Comment: What do you mean by "read the file from outside"?

Comment: means that the file is saved on hard drive. i am not creating it on assembly codes

Comment: It's ok. Your code reads a file, any file, it doesn't matter how it was created. Just check if file exists.

Comment: Many C-based huffman encoding schemes can be found at https://www.google.com/webhp?q=c+huffman+code, if you were interested in that.

Comment: i should look at it. but i have to do it in assembly language. Thanks